# Test Nginx Config without File on Disk

Tags: nginx

I've learned that you can test a config without having to deploy it via:

```
sudo nginx -t -c /home/ubuntu/test/example.conf
```

But what if I'm on a non-writable filesystem? Is there any way nginx can take in the config via a string on the command line?  Or, is there any other program or helper script which can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a writable root, you should be using something like `tmpfs` for /tmp that is writable. Much of *nix userland software simply expects /tmp to be writable.

```
$ tf=$(mktemp)
$ sed -e "s/#customer_ip#/$ip/g" /etc/nginx/nginx-template.conf >$tf
$ nginx -t -c $tf
nginx: the configuration file /tmp/tmp.lZ6HpnxWqE syntax is okay
```

Some shells have a shorthand for this:

```
$ zsh -c 'nginx -t -c =(sed -e "s/#customer_ip#/$ip/g" /etc/nginx/nginx-template.conf)'
```

**Relative `include` paths referencing other nginx config snippets such as `include fastcgi.conf;` in your (temporary or process-substituted) config file will not work.** You would have to replace those with absolute paths, e.g.: `include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;`

Comment: Are you sure the pipe magic works?  I get the same result for`nginx -t -c <(echo "invalid file****")`
`nginx: the configuration file /dev/fd/63 syntax is ok
2017/10/18 08:42:57 [emerg] 3357#3357: no "events" section in 
configuration
nginx: configuration file /dev/fd/63 test failed`

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch oh i was. but i stand corrected, your counterexample is convincing.

Comment: And yes, I wish we had tmpfs or something like that, but unfortunately I didn't make the server set-up.  It's a series of immutable Docker containers with no tmpfs.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Our company has a hosting department which tries its hardest to make everything a thousand times more secure than it needs to be.  Making our lives difficult is their #1 goal.